# Google clouds billing cannot establish payments profile

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-pay

I'm currently new to using Google Clouds (with payment of course)  and i've been trying to connect it with my payment info. I'm currently using a debit Master card and living in Africa, (maybe if the location has impact) , and after step 2 right after verifying it's me, it displays a pop up menu, `This action couldn’t be completed. Try again later. [OR-CBAT-15]` with this code. what does this mean? and how can i connect my billing account? or is there another way to make payment?[image: this is the pop up]

Comment: Check with the issuer of your debit card. Ask them why they declined Google. Ask them to approve future charges. Not all debit cards support recurring charges and identity verification. Ask the issuer if those features are supported.

Comment: @JohnHanley it's been verified when change is made.

Comment: What has been verified? Your card is declined which means NOTHING has been verified. Call the issuer of your card as I mentioned and ask them. Otherwise use another card that meets Google's requirements.

Comment: can i use paypal or Gpay?

Comment: Google does accept PayPal. However, I do not know if you can open a GCP account with PayPal but you can pay after the account is open. If you have a valid Google Pay account, are you using the same identity and card information with Google Cloud? Google provides documentation on Google Cloud billing, payments, etc. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes i did read but GCP doesn't support my country. does that affect the billing process? and i'm new to billing so ...

Comment: Provide the link that says Google does not support Africa. I personally know of many Google customers in Africa. If you want help, answer each question asked and provide information after calling your debit card issuer. Edit your post with everything I have asked for.

Comment: @JohnHanley https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9306917 you can't find ethiopia here

Comment: That link is for Android and Google Play. That is not for Google Cloud. However, you link shows that Africa IS supported for those services.

Comment: @JohnHanley okay i'll ask again after contacting my card issuer